# Can GoogleFinance access total return data?

Tags: asset-allocation, historical-data, google-finance

I'd like to be able to access historical total (market) return data from a Google Sheet with the end goal of creating a self-updating rolling return histogram of various asset allocations.

However, it looks like the [GoogleFinance](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=155178&from=54198&rd=1) functions in Google Sheets can only access share prices, not dividends.  For this data to be useful to me, I would like to include the effects of reinvesting the dividends.  I don't know of what use historical data is without any indication of dividend returns.

Is there a way to include dividends in a Google docs spreadsheet?  Or even better, is there an online tool that will already show histograms (or show some variance metric) for various distributions?

Comment: +1 from me.  Community: Why are people downvoting this question without commenting? Please, consider it impolite to do so.  If you think a question can be improved, try and say how.  Drive-by downvotes are seldom helpful.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea thanks.  I have been experiencing this (downvotes without comments) with my other questions as well and it's quite discouraging--and I think harmful to the fledgling site's future.

Comment: @glenviewjeff - Yahoo data is adjusted, so numbers at two end points will reflect dividends and splits. Have you looked at Yahoo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, Google Finance doesn't support historical return or dividend data, only share prices.  The attributes for mutual funds such as `return52` are only available as real-time data, not historical.

Yahoo Finance offers "adjusted return" prices for many tickers, which reflect total returns. Normally, one cannot access this data from within Google Sheets, but there is a plugin from WebDataHub.com that presently costs at least $19/month for their service.

There is also an [article that walks you through how to write Google Apps Script](https://medium.com/codex/how-to-import-yahoo-finance-data-into-google-spreadsheets-834e6a7f82c3) that will allow Google Sheets to scrape data from Yahoo Finance.

Comment: I take it you didn't find an online tool to show the histograms you were looking for? Otherwise you didn't answer your own question.

Comment: @JohnBensin no, I haven't.  The question is still open.

Comment: I guess I'm confused why you would answer your own question immediately if you don't have an answer for it.

Comment: @JohnBensin It is an answer--it shows how to access total return data from GoogleFinance.  It does not answer the "better yet, ...histograms" part, which is why the answer has not been accepted.  Though if nobody else can find a canned solution, I will accept my own answer after the waiting period.

Comment: Except that the Google Finance data doesn't account for dividends, which is part of what you're asking about. I guess it seems strange when someone asks a question and immediately posts a fairly low-quality answer to it. Mind you, I'm not penalizing/downvoting you for it (you can check my [reputation](http://money.stackexchange.com/users/7590/john-bensin?tab=reputation) to see that), but it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same answer as for your other question, but you can easily do this yourself:

( initial adjusted close / final adjusted close ) ^ ( 1 / ( # of years sampled) )

Note: "# of years sampled" can be a fraction, so the one week # of years sampled would be 1/52.

---

Crazy to say, but yahoo finance is better at quick, easy, and free data.  Just pick a security, go to historical prices, and use the "adjusted close".

money.msn's best at presenting finances quick, easy, and cheap.

Comment: How does this account for dividends?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question--as far as I can tell, there is no adjusted close data accessible from GoogleFinance.

Comment: I don't see how recommending Yahoo is going to answer the question either, unless it will `already show histograms (or show some variance metric) for various distributions`

Comment: @glenviewjeff Why are you strictly bound to use Google Finance? There are numerous data sources out there (of similarly mediocre quality) that *do* provide adjusted closing prices. Alternatively, there are plenty of data sources with much more robust data packages. See [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/21707/7590).

Comment: @glenviewjeff Also, making histograms is a simple process in MATLAB, Stata, R, Excel, etc. so once you have the data it's *trivial* to make your own. I don't imagine a website is going to offer intermediate metrics like that for free, especially not when you could make them so easily on your own.

Comment: @JohnBensin GoogleFinance is free and has direct access to financial data rather than having to manually import or paste large volumes of data.

Comment: @glenviewjeff Yahoo offers free direct access to financial data as well and many other data providers will offer an API, which is about as automatic as you can get. I don't think using an API is much work if it gives you the flexibility to create what you need (especially since it looks like Google Finance *doesn't* offer you the charts you need anyway).

Comment: @JohnBensin by direct access to the data I meant that the Google Drive spreadsheet has direct access to the data--as opposed to R, Matlab, Octave, etc. which rely on you importing/storing your data locally.  As far as I know, there is no equivalent to GoogleFinance on Yahoo, and I'm not interested in writing an application to access Yahoo's API and present the output with Gnuplot or equivalent.

Comment: @glenviewjeff But if GF doesn't offer you the data that you want, you're stuck, and need to pursue another solution. How badly do you want these histograms?

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy I just checked Yahoo and they do not appear to offer market return data including dividends.  For example, the S&P 500 index does not account for dividends--the S&P ^SPXTR index does, but is unavailable through Yahoo Finance.

Comment: +1 @JoeCoderGuy I didn't think of looking at SPY on Yahoo instead of ^INX.