# Is there an online service that provides public company information through a public API?

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing, online-data-source

I want to write an application to gather financial information of public companies and bonds for my own research. Is there any place online that I can do this that has a public API?

Comment: Bloomberg, Reuters, etc. That's what they do.

Comment: Many data companies provide an API to access the SEC's [EDGAR](http://www.sec.gov/edgar.shtml) system; is that the sort of data you're looking for?

Comment: basically. edgar looks to be very close to what i want. i can parse text and do etl on the data i just need to find where to access it. thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any free API's for these data, but I'll provide what information I can. Compiling all of this information from the [EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/edgar.shtml) system and exposing an interface to it requires a fair amount of work and maintenance, so it's usually market data companies that have the motivation and resources to provide such interfaces. I know of a few options that may or may not be close to what you're looking for.

1. The SEC provides [FTP access](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/ftpusers.htm) to the EDGAR system. You could download and parse the text files they provide.
2. Yahoo Finance provides summary files of financial statements (e.g., [GOOG](http://biz.yahoo.com/e/130129/goog10-k.html)) as well as links to the full statements in the EDGAR system. Once again, parsing may be your only option for these data.
3. Xignite, a proprietary market data provider, provides a [financial statement API](http://www.xignite.com/product/company-financials/). If you need these data for a commercial application, you could contact them and work something out. (Frankly, if you need these data for a commercial application, [you're probably better off paying for the data](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/21707/7590))
4. The [Center for Research into Security Prices](http://www.crsp.chicagobooth.edu/index.html) provides data from financial statements. I believe it's also exposed through several of their API's. As with most financial data, CRSP is sort of a gold standard, although I haven't personally used their API to fetch data from financial statements, so I can't speak for it specifically.
5. [This answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3693189) mentions the quantmod R package and [mergent](http://www.mergent.com/). I can't vouch for either of those options personally.

Unfortunately, you'll probably have to do some parsing unless you can find a paid data provider that's already compiled this information in a machine-readable format.

Comment: parsing isn't a big deal for me, i just didn't know where to go to access it! thank you!